# French Fries Vs Fries

Tags: word-usage

I went into an argument with a good speaker in my country if native speakers call french fries but just simply as fries (when they order).

Which is correct?

Do native speakers say only "fries" when they order "french fries" such as at McDonald?

Comment: You will usually lose an argument when you use all-encompassing terms like "nobody" or "everyone" or "never."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are used. Just "fries" is probably more common, just because it's simpler to say, the same way usually we say "fridge" instead of "refrigerator" or "taxi" instead of "taxi cab".

Comment: Fun fact, in Philippine English they say *ref* instead of *fridge*. : )

Comment: @userr2684291, but then who calls fouls in your soccer games?